# Why does sunspot/solr seem to lose most indexed search results on server reboot until it's manually reindexed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Has anyone else run into this issue?

I have a startup script that runs a start and reindex command for sunspot/solr. When the server reboots, the service does start. But for some reason the search results still don't show up in my app until I manually run the reindex. So not only do the results disappear on reboot for some reason, the start up script's reindex doesn't seem to do anything.

Before you ask, I am sure that the script runs, because if I don't have it, I get Solr connection errors indicating the service is not even started. But even if I figure out the reason why the reindex doesn't seem to happen, I am more baffled by the fact that most sunspot/solr search results are lost on reboot, and need to be re-added by reindexing.

Comment: That seems… quite strange. I suspect you'll need to add more information about your server environment before anyone can really give you useful feedback.

Comment: You should start debugging this by checking if the data and index files on server exist after a reboot. If they don't, you want to look into the whole configuration stuff to see why its not writing the index.

Comment: This problem did go away, and I have no idea what caused it or resolved it. I do a few releases a week via Capistrano and something must have done the job. Thanks for the feedback.